# Bootstrap error on nested path in React JS Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

While this routing works for /verify_email but doesn't work for /verify_email/test:

```
<Router>
      <AuthProvider>
        <Fragment>
          <Switch>
           <Route path="/business_owner_signup">
              <MerchantSignup />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/verify_email/test">
            <MerchantSignupStep3Onwards />
            </Route>
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </Fragment>
      </AuthProvider>
    </Router>
```

I am getting a strange error in Bootstrap and couldn't find any relation on Google:

[image: exception_bootstrap_on_nested_path]

Error stack:

```
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
D:/React/OMW/project/onmyway_web/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6
__webpack_require__
D:/React/OMW/project/onmyway_web/webpack/bootstrap:784
  781 | };
  782 | 
  783 | // Execute the module function
> 784 | modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  785 | 
  786 | // Flag the module as loaded
  787 | module.l = true;
View compiled
fn
D:/React/OMW/project/onmyway_web/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
```

Comment: It seems like you need to install jQuery in order to use Bootstrap's Javascript functions and methods.

Comment: jQuery is already there ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly basic error:

In index.js
I was using :

> import $ from 'jquery';

Instead I had to use :

> import 'jquery/src/jquery';

So, it wasn't picking up the jquery!

Answer (score 1):

Need to reinstall react-webpack
"npm i react-webpack"

System Requirements:
"npm i webpack, bower, webpack-dev-server, -g"

Comment: webpack wasn't there
Added webpack but din't help.
react-webpack": "^0.4.1 .
but getting same error!

Comment: added in the issue above